# Bootstrap 2 ---> 3 navbar issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple navbar wich collapses fine. When the menu is collapsed I'm using the script below to "auto hide" the menu when I click on a menue item:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.navbar-collapse.in').removeClass('.in').css('height', '0');                     
});
```

This worked perfect in BS2 but now the menu won't close fully anymore and I have to click twice on the toggle button to open it again. It can be a little hard to notice the difference but look at the bottom of the second picture.

Menu before close:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXeb8.png

Menu after close:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1ZSu.png

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Tab6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Tab7</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">Tab8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you state the question a little more precise?

Comment: When I open my collapsed navbar and click on the tabs the navbar closes using the script above. But then it wont fully close as seen in picture 2. Are you with me?

Comment: I'm testing in windows 8 and latest chrome to be specific =)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
       $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');                    
});
```